# Adding information to dataGridView's column

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a cycle for (j = 1; j <= x; j ++) in my programme. In it, if the variable x>1, then dataGridView adds a column, there is a certain element of the array a[j].
How to add a[j] to the new column?

```
for (j = 1; j <= x; j++)
{
   a[j] = (f - z) / x;
   dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column" + j, "Помічник №" + j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells["columnj"].Value =a[j];
```

Change RowIndex to suite your program